# Android connect to webservice, org.apache.http depricated?

Tags: java, android, web-services

```
 import   com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.Interfaces.ODKortrijkInterface;
 import com.example.hoofdgebruiker.winkelskortrijk.Model.Winkel;


public class ODKortrijkWebservice extends AsyncTask<ODKortrijkInterface, Void, String>{
private ODKortrijkInterface listener;
@Override
protected String doInBackground(ODKortrijkInterface... arg0) {
    listener = arg0[0];

    StringBuilder newsBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    // execute search

    try {
        //HttpGet newsGet = new HttpGet("http://data.drk.be/kortrijk/nieuws.xml");
        HttpGet newsGet = new HttpGet("http://data.kortrijk.be/nieuws/rss.xml");
        HttpResponse newsResponse = newsClient.execute(newsGet);
        StatusLine newsSearchStatus = newsResponse
                .getStatusLine();

        if (newsSearchStatus.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            // we have an OK response
            HttpEntity newsEntity = newsResponse.getEntity();
            InputStream placesContent = newsEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader placesInput = new InputStreamReader(
                    placesContent);
            BufferedReader placesReader = new BufferedReader(
                    placesInput);

            String lineIn;
            while ((lineIn = placesReader.readLine()) != null) {
                newsBuilder.append(lineIn);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newsBuilder.toString();
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItems = processResult(result);
    listener.updateScreen(newsItems);
}

private ArrayList<NewsItem> processResult(String result){
    ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItems = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
    NewsItem newsItem= new NewsItem();
    try {
        // parse XML
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(result));

        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        boolean isItem = false;
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                    newsItem= new NewsItem();
                    isItem=true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title") && isItem){
                    xpp.next();
                    newsItem.setTitle(xpp.getText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link") && isItem){
                    xpp.next();
                    newsItem.setLink(xpp.getText());
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("description") && isItem){
                    xpp.next();
                    newsItem.setDescription(xpp.getText());
                    newsItems.add(newsItem);
                    isItem=false;
                }
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return newsItems;
}
}
```

I have to make something similar, but for a different webservice. However, the org.apache.http imports aren't working in the newer versions. I could just go back to older versions, but that doesn't really seem optimal. What's the current way to do something like this (connect to a webservice and read data)? Anyone can give me a simple example, or explain what I should do? Thank you

Comment: You should read the documentation of the deprecated classes, to see how you can migrate it

Comment: Which type of web service you are accessing, RESTful or SOAP?

Comment: @MonishKamble http://data.kortrijk.be/middenstand/winkels_markten

Comment: @Jens I have to write completely new code, so I want to do it the proper way (so as it should be done right now). No point in learning something thats not supposed to be used anymore

Comment: Ok. then your question is off- Topic "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: @Well I just want to change this so it works, not by using the old way but by using the new way (so not using deprecated classes). I'm not just looking for a tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Now Android is supporting HttpURLConnection instead of Apache Http,

You can find some references here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Also you should check Retrofit:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/